# how jquery handles map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, maven

Iam doing a spring mvc project with maven..I want to display a jqxGrid with items..am getting the item through MAP..The problem is ,i got grid but no items displaying..the data return from controller by map..how jquery handles this returning map ??

my jquery code

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
             var source =
                {     
                    datatype: "json",
                    type:"GET",
                    url: "account/list",
                    datafields: [
                        { name: 'id' },
                        { name: 'periodname' },
                        { name: 'startdate' },
                        { name: 'enddate' },
                        { name: 'isactive' }
                    ],
                    sort: function () {
                        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('updatebounddata', 'sort');
                        },

                    id: 'id'
                };


             var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {

                        }
             });

$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {

            width: 800,
            source: dataAdapter,
            pageable: true,

            autoheight: true,

            columns: [
              { text: 'Period Name', datafield: 'periodname', width: 200 },
              { text: 'Start Date', datafield: 'startdate', width: 200 },
              { text: 'End Date', datafield: 'enddate', width: 200 },
              { text: 'Active', datafield: 'isactive', width: 200 }
            ]
        });

        $("#addrowbutton").jqxButton({ theme: theme });
        $("#deleterowbutton").jqxButton({ theme: theme });
        $("#updaterowbutton").jqxButton({ theme: theme });

        // initialize jqxGrid
               // });
    });
    </script>
```

controller

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping(value="/account")
 public class AccountsController {
@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;
@Autowired
private AccountDAO accountDao;

 @RequestMapping(value="/list",method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
 @ResponseBody
 public Map<String, Object> getAccounts(Map<String, Object> map) {

    map.put("all_item_issue_headers", accountDao.getAccounts());
    System.out.println(map);
    return map;

}
}
```

waiting for your response..thanks

Comment: do you have proper annotations at your controller?

Comment: now i include my controller..

Comment: one more thing what is the output of it `return map;` its an object `{}` or array of objects `[{}, {}, ...n]`

Comment: it is like this {all_item_issue_headers=[com.gerrytan.pizzashop.Accounts@1d7efa3, com.gerrytan.pizzashop.Accounts@1b5d60d, com.gerrytan.pizzashop.Accounts@f805e6, com.gerrytan.pizzashop.Accounts@14b5721, com.gerrytan.pizzashop.Accounts@145468d, com.gerrytan.pizzashop.Accounts@11af268, com.gerrytan.pizzashop.Accounts@209197]}

Comment: I assume you want to return JSON. Do you have the jackson libs in your classpath?

Comment: yes i want to return in JSON

Answer (score 3):

The response will be a json. The key it's `all_item_issue_headers`.

```
  var response = yourJson; // this is the map

  var array = yourJson[all_item_issue_headers]; // this is an array
```